# Python Starting Thread From Function Inside Class TypeError takes 2 positional args but 3 were given

Tags: python, class

```
    def tfunc(this.args.dir, folder):
      for file in os.listdir(folder):
        this.executeFile(os.path.join(this.args.dir, file))

    def executeFiles(this):
      for folders1 in os.listdir(this.args.dir):
        for folders2 in os.listdir("downloaded/" + os.path.join(folders1)):
            t = threading.Thread(target=this.tfunc, args=(this, folders2))
            t.start()
```

Just like the title says, I've tried wtih a comma after last argument to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Edit: Reproducible code. Sorry for not posting this directly.Now I can't add the code because it says that there is too much code and not enough text so I'm writing as much as possible here to bne able to post the code.

```
class MoodysParser :

def complete(this) :
    print(f"Complete")
    exit()

def executeFile(this, filename):
    print(filename)
    

def tfunc(dir, folder):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        this.executeFile(os.path.join(dir, file))

def executeFiles(this):
    for folders1 in os.listdir(this.args.dir):
        for folders2 in os.listdir("downloaded/" + os.path.join(folders1)):
            t = threading.Thread(target=this.tfunc, args=(this.args.dir, folders2))
            t.start()



def execute(this) :
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
    this.timestamp = int(time.time());
    this.dir = os.path.dirname(__file__);
    this.out_fn = f"moodys-results-{this.timestamp}.csv";
    this.file_x = 1
    this.fields_template = {};
    this.fields_template["company"] = "";
    this.fields_template["telephone"] = "";
    this.fields_template["address"] = "";
    this.fields_template["telephone2"] = "";
    this.fields_template["link_id"] = "";
    this.fields_template["location_type"] = "";
    this.fields_template["industry"] = "";
    this.fields_template["sales_range"] = "";
    this.fields_template["employees"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_risk_increase"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_overall_payments"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_peer_payments"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_bankruptcy"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_tax_liens"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_financial_news"] = "";
    this.fields_template["alerts_ucc_filings"] = "";
    this.fields_template["number_reviews"] = "";
    this.fields_template["average_rating"] = "";
    this.fields_template["reviews"] = "";
    this.firstrun = not os.path.isfile(this.out_fn)
    this.out = open(this.out_fn, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8");
    print(f"Opening {this.out_fn}");
    this.writer = csv.writer(this.out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL);
    this.out.write(b'\xEF\xBB\xBF'.decode())
    this.writer.writerow(this.fields_template.keys());
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dir', type=str, required=True);
    parser.add_argument('--max', type=int);
    parser.add_argument('--debug', action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction);
    this.args = parser.parse_args();
    if not os.path.isdir(this.args.dir):
        print(f"Input directory does not exist")
        exit()
    this.executeFiles()
    this.complete();
```

scraper = MoodysParser();
scraper.execute();

Comment: can you share the actual full stacktrace?

Comment: Please, post [mre] and full traceback you get. What class, there is no class whatsover in the code snippet

Comment: @RonSerruya Stacktrace is over the limit that is permitted by Stack Overflow. It just repeats the same error in every thread. Saying 2 positional arguments are taken but 3 were given.

Comment: @buran Added, sorry for not posting this directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass `this` to `args`. `this` would be passed to `tfunc` automatically.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=this.tfunc, args=(folders2, ))
```